# How to use pandas set_index if the columns have no name and consist only "rangeindex"

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make column[0] (i.e. Lease income, Manage, etc.) to be my index:
[image]

After indexing, the vertical column at the left side should be removed, which should look like:
[image]

I could do it manually just by copying the column[0] to be its index and removing afterward the column[0]:

```
income_df.index = income_df[0]
income_df.index.name = 'Category'
income_df = income_df.drop(0, axis = 1)
```

But line 1 and 3 seem redundant to me.

Normally IF the headers were not `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)` but consist of names (e.g.: Category, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4), I would just use:

```
df.set_index('Category')
```

Could I use `set_index` to perform the indexing for column without name strings?
If so how?

Comment: `df.set_index([0]).rename_index(index='Category')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns still have "labels" per se, they just happen to be [0, 1, 2, 3,...]. So you can still use `set_index` to set the index just like you would with any other column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", 4]])

print(df.columns)
print(df)

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
```

setting the index:

```
new_df = df.set_index(0)

print(new_df)
   1
0   
a  1
b  2
c  3
d  4
```